# Alternative for switch statement, drill down Table Views?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6, switch-statement

I need to create a drill down effect with my table views that will expand four table views deep for each of my original cells in my master table view. So far i was successful in populating the master view, and second table view accordingly with this Object Oriented Method, here is the code in my master table view:

```
 class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    let aSport:[Sport] = {
        var basketball = Sport()
        basketball.name = "Basketball"
        basketball.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["International Basketball","Wheelchair Basketball","Beach Basketball","Deaf Basketball","Dwarf Basketball"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        var golf = Sport()
        golf.name = "Golf"
        golf.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["Miniature Golf","Dart Golf","Sholf","Disc Golf","Footgolf"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        var football = Sport()
        football.name = "Football"
        football.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["Flag Football","Indoor Football","Arena Football","Non-Tackle Football","Paper Football"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        var swimming = Sport()
        swimming.name = "Swimming"
        swimming.sportCategories = {
            var temp = ["Competitive Swimming","Synchronized Swimming","Duo Swimming","Relay Swimming"]
            temp.sort(<)
            return temp
            }()

        return  [basketball,golf,football,swimming]
        }()

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return aSport.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = aSport[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let row = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row
        let detail = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
        detail.selectedSport = aSport[row!]
    }


}


class Sport {

    var name: String = "sport name"
    var sportCategories: NSArray = ["variations of selected sport"]
    var detailText: NSArray = ["little description of sport"]

}
```

here is the code in my second table view controller:

```
class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var selectedSport = Sport();


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return selectedSport.sportCategories.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Custom", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = selectedSport.sportCategories[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = selectedSport.detailText[indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell
}

}
```

here are screenshots from my simulator so you get a visual:

https://40.media.tumblr.com/6ee47f49c2b223b514f8067c68ac6af1/tumblr_nqbe74HYGo1tupbydo1_500.png

when basketball is selected:

https://41.media.tumblr.com/ced0ee2ff111a557ec3c21f1fb765adf/tumblr_nqbe74HYGo1tupbydo2_500.png

Now as you can see, i was able to populate the first two views by creating a custom class, creating custom objects of that class and using the properties within the class. Now my dilemma is, each of the "sportCategories" properties have their OWN table views to expand to which will consist of a whole list of names of players in that respective sport. Now what method should i go about doing this? should i create a whole new class in my second table view controller to give the sportsCategories their own properties? or is there a way i can already expand off the work I've already done? a more efficient way?

Comment: Are all of these child view controllers the same basic layout, just with different data, or are they radically different in terms of UI?

Comment: same basic layout, just with different data @i_am_jorf

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what I was asking for in your last question. You still haven't said anything about the structure of your data. What objects are you using to populate the first table view? Do you have custom objects?

Comment: no custom objects, simple UITableViewCells @rdelmar

Comment: I didn't ask about cells, I asked about data. Tell me this. How are you populating the 1st cell table view now? How is what you populate that table with related to what you have in the first row of the initial table view? If you can't or won't describe your data structure, I can't help you.

Comment: ok let me break it down. my original 21 cells are all SPORTS, and the nested table views within those are branches of those sports. EXAMPLE: cell 1 in my "MainTableViewController" is GOLF. when selected it transitions to "1st cell table view"(as you know) and it lists branches of golf such as miniature golf,LPGA, etc. @rdelmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one detail controller, you don't need the switch statement at all. The best (most object oriented) way to do this would be to use custom objects to populate your cells. You could create a `Sport` object that would have two properties, `name (NSString)`, and `categories (NSArray)`. In the master table view controller, you would create all the `Sport` objects, and add them to an array, `sports`. You would use `sports` to populate the array with,

```
let aSport = sports[indexPath.row] as! Sport
cell.textLabel.text = aSport.name
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you create an instance of `DetailViewController`, set the value of a property in that class (lets call it `selectedSport`), and push it,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let detailVC = DetailViewController()
    detailVC.selectedSport = sports[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
}
```

In `DetailViewController`, you would use `selectedSport.categories` to populate the table view. Since you have access to the whole `Sport` object, you could use `selectedSport.name` to provide the title for the controller.

Comment: that makes sense but what if it doesn't just stop at the DetailViewController? let me FULLY ARTICULATE. my original 21 cells are all SPORTS, and the nested table views within those are branches of those sports. EXAMPLE: cell 1 in my "MainTableViewController" is GOLF. when selected it transitions to "1st cell table view"(as you know) and it lists branches of golf such as miniature golf,LPGA, etc. Now When one of THOSE cells are selected, they must also transition into one of their own table views. so in total ALL 21 of my original cells, have 3 nested table views inside them.

Comment: so is your solution still apply if it goes past just one DetailViewController?

Comment: @RobertTillman Sure, it can go as deep as you want, but you need the correct data structure to support it. Suppose that the categories array wasn't just a list of strings, like miniature golf,LPGA, etc., but that those were Golf objects. Golf objects could have a name property (which is what populates the second table view), and it could have other properties that apply to miniature golf or LPGA, etc. that you would use to populate the third level table view (to which you would pass the selected Golf object, like you passed the selected Sport object to the second level table view).

Comment: oh ok i see i see. so create my original 21 cells as objects, and the next two views would essentially be their properties @rdelmar

Comment: @RobertTillman Not the cells, but the data for those 21 cells would be an array of objects, yes, and the following table views are populated by properties of those objects (or sub-objects).

Comment: when you say crete these custom sport objects, i would have to create a custom class first correct @rdelmar

Comment: & do i have to implement 3 different detail view controllers in my IB being that i have 3 nested table views to transition to for each row in my original controller? do i have to use the IB at all? or is this done all programmatically ?

Comment: @RobertTillman, you should have 3 view controllers with table views in them in the storyboard (although, you could do it all programmatically if you want). I wouldn't call that "nested" though. The first one should be embedded in a navigation controller, and you should hook the others up with "show" segues.

Comment: I'm having an issue populating the First View with the Array, the" let aSport = sports[indexPath.row] as! Sport
cell.textLabel.text = aSport.name" action is being denied ?

Comment: @RobertTillman What do you mean by "action is being denied"? Are you getting an error on running, to a compile error? If so, on which line, and what error do you get?

Comment: never mind that, a syntax in my code was off. i was able to populate the first view with the sports names, however, in your explanation of the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" in the master table view, can you elaborate on "set the value of a property in that class (lets call it selectedSport)"? do i set the instance of DetailViewController(DetailVC) to a property in my newly created custom class? being the cateogories property you mean??

Comment: @RobertTillman I'm not sure what you're asking. I showed the code you should use in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. The property, selectedSport, is a property that you would create in the detail view controller.

Comment: so you mean aside from the custom sport class i created in my master table view, i should create a class in my DetailViewController containing exactly what? i understand selectedSport is a property created in the Detail view controller but of what class? an individual class for a specific sport or?

Comment: @RobertTillman, You're selecting a Sport object in you master table, so that's what you want to pass. selectedSport should be typed as Sport.

Comment: i understand but you said selectedSport is a property i would create in my DetailViewController. to create a property i need an object, and to create an object i need a class. what class should i create in my detail view ? aside from the class i created in my main view that contain all the sport objects with name and categories ?

Comment: @RobertTillman, you seem to have some misunderstandings about objects and classes. You do not need an object to create a property. The property should be declared as Sport (you need to import `Sport.h` into the detail controller's .m file, and put in an `@class Sport;` line in the .h file to make the DetailViewController class aware of that class). You don't need to create any class in the DetailViewController.

Comment: well I'm not using obj c so what code would i need to import the class to my detail view in swift? and to sum up what I've done at this point, i created a custom sport class and 21 sport objects that contain the properties "name" and "categories". i have successfully populated the main table view with the "name" property of each object now all i want to do is push the corresponding cateogories with the correct sports name when selected to my detail view. so you say create a new property in my detail?

Comment: @RobertTillman, sorry, I forgot this was Swift, you shouldn't need to import anything. I don't know what else to tell you. I showed you the code you should have in didSelectRowAtIndexPath to send the selected Sport object to the detail controller. In the detail controller, you need `var selectedSport: Sport!` at the top of your class. You should then be able to get the categories and anything else you need from selectedSport.

Comment: no i fully understand, i just wanted to clarify. but it seems when i add this variable to the top of my detail view, its labeled "undeclared", are you positive theres no import statement that should be applied?

Comment: @RobertTillman All I can say is that in my experience with Swift, I've never had to import one of my own classes (only things like UIKit or Foundation which usually get added for you). You didn't mark your Sport class private did you?

Comment: how do i uncover if i did or not?

Comment: i made it an independent class not a subclass

Comment: @RobertTillman if you didn't put "private" in front of the class name, then its not. If you did, delete the "private". It doesn't matter whether your class is a subclass of something or not.  You should ask a new question about this. Show the code you have in the Sport class, and the master and detail classes. I can't keep guessing what you're doing wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: i fixed it, just had to prefix it correctly. and thats why i asked you for a separate fourm in which i can possibly just send you screenshots of my code, or we can chat one on one. I don't really like asking questions just for the sake of asking, especially when it can be resolved by one person viewing my code, (being you)

Comment: @RobertTillman I created a chat room if you still have questions. It is here, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/79820/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-robert-tillman?tab=general

Comment: can you check the chat one last time please @rdelmar

Answer (score 0):

If the hierarchy is just from the main view controller to one of 21 specific view controllers and back (not 21 nested view controllers), and the behaviour of all these 21 tables is very similar, then there isn't really much reason to have 21 view controllers. Have one view controllers for all the 21 displays, then before you switch to it you tell it what data to display, and of course it has to be able to display the data of all 21 views. (If you had 15 views looking one way and 6 views looking a different way, you would use two view controllers).

(I don't like making things depending on a row index. That just makes it very difficult if you want to arrange the rows in a different way).

Comment: but how do i change the data source in the switch?